# Cordova plugin & storyboard files

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

.storyboard files aren't being added to the ios bundle list when I run:

```
ionic platform add ios
```

Is there a solution for this other than manually doing it?

Answer (score -1):

Kept plugging and realized I needed to add .storyboard files to the plugin.xml registration.  That fixed it for me.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you share the plugin.xml line that fixed it?

Comment: You can use <resource-file src="...">